# NHibernate QueryOver how to join on non declared relationship

Tags: nhibernate, join, queryover

How to do the following join to return Users who have access to a Company given a company id.
The problem is there is no explicit relationship using a User object between UserAccess and User they simply join on the string property Username:

```
User(Username, Name)
UserAccess(Username, Company)
Company(Id)

Session.QueryOver<Company>()
        .Where(c => c.Id == companyId)
        .JoinQueryOver<UserCompanyAccess>(u => u.UserAccessList)
        .JoinQueryOver<User>(u => **Nope no property, just a string**
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378224/nhibernate-queryover-to-join-unrelated-entities

Answer (score 11, accepted):

could be done with a subquery

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Company>()
    .Where(c => c.Id == companyId)
    .JoinQueryOver<UserCompanyAccess>(u => u.UserAccessList)
    .Select(uca => uca.UserName);

var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(u => u.Name).In(subquery)
    .List();
```

Answer (score 5):

As of 5.1.0, it is possible to make hibernate generate an actual sql join on an undeclared (unmapped) relationship. E.g. all orders sorted by customer's spending:

```
var criteria = _session
    .CreateCriteria<Order>("order");

criteria
    .CreateEntityAlias(
        "customer",
        Restrictions.EqProperty("order.customerId", "customer._id"),
        JoinType.LeftOuterJoin,
        typeof(Customer).FullName)
    .AddOrder(new Order("customer._lifetimeSpending", ascending:false));

return criteria.List<Order>();
```

Also possible with QueryOver (sample from [NHibernate docs](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html)):

```
Cat cat = null;
Cat joinedCat = null;

var uniquelyNamedCats = sess.QueryOver<Cat>(() => cat)
    .JoinEntityAlias(
        () => joinedCat,
        () => cat.Name == joinedCat.Name && cat.Id != joinedCat.Id,
        JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Where(() => joinedCat.Id == null)
    .List();
```